# JSX element type 'SubscribeCard' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to use react-subscribe-card module for email subscription in react.js.

this is my code in popup.tsx.

```
import React from "react";
import SubscribeCard from "react-subscribe-card";

const mailchimpURL = `[Your Mailchimp subscription URL]`;

const outerCardStyle = `
      padding: 0;
      box-shadow: 0px 5px 35px 0px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.17);
    `;
const subContainerStyle = `
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px -1px rgba(50,50,93,.25), 0 1px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
      align-items: center;
    `;
const subInputStyle = `
      border-width: 0;
      margin: 0;
    `;
const subButtonStyle = `
      border-radius: 0;
      flex-grow: 1;
      background-color: #fdfdfd;
      color: #000000;
    `;

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <SubscribeCard
      mailchimpURL={mailchimpURL}
      outerCardStyle={outerCardStyle}
      subContainerStyle={subContainerStyle}
      subInputStyle={subInputStyle}
      subButtonStyle={subButtonStyle}
    />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

but I get this error

> JSX element type 'SubscribeCard' does not have any construct or call
> signatures.

plz help me to fix.
thanks

Comment: So your  popup.tsx file conatains App component ? do you have another file called App.js or App.tsx ?

Comment: Works for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-jepsen-0n9ul?file=/src/App.js. Are you on the latest version of `react-subscribe-card`? Or maybe there was a problem with its installation.

Comment: thanks for your response. but my file is tsx file. if js file, it works well. but if tsx file, it doesn't work and get above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in declaration [file](https://github.com/thomaswang/react-subscribe-card/blob/master/src/index.d.ts)

As you might have noticed, there is no type for `SubscribeCard`

You can create a PR or just use this workaround:

```js
import React from "react";
import { SubscribeCard, Props } from "react-subscribe-card";

declare module "react-subscribe-card" {
  type ExtendedProps = {
    mailchimpURL: string;
    outerCardStyle: string;
    subContainerStyle: string;
    subInputStyle: string;
    subButtonStyle: string;
  };
  var SubscribeCard: React.ComponentClass<Props & ExtendedProps>;
}


const mailchimpURL = `[Your Mailchimp subscription URL]`;

const outerCardStyle = `
      padding: 0;
      box-shadow: 0px 5px 35px 0px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.17);
    `;
const subContainerStyle = `
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px -1px rgba(50,50,93,.25), 0 1px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
      align-items: center;
    `;
const subInputStyle = `
      border-width: 0;
      margin: 0;
    `;
const subButtonStyle = `
      border-radius: 0;
      flex-grow: 1;
      background-color: #fdfdfd;
      color: #000000;
    `;

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <SubscribeCard
      mailchimpURL={mailchimpURL}
      outerCardStyle={outerCardStyle}
      subContainerStyle={subContainerStyle}
      subInputStyle={subInputStyle}
      subButtonStyle={subButtonStyle}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Please keep in mind that you did not provide all required props.